# Rearrange/mix column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, multiple-columns

i have table like this:

| ID | Type | I/P | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Primary | I | 8 |
| ID2 | Primary | I | 3 |
| ID3 | Secondary | P | 6 |
| ID4 | Secondary | I | 2 |
| ID5 | Primary | P | 3 |
| ID6 | Primary | I | 4 |

I re order it this way:

| ID | Type | I/P | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Primary | I | 8 |
| ID6 | Primary | I | 4 |
| ID2 | Primary | I | 3 |
| ID5 | Primary | P | 3 |
| ID3 | Secondary | P | 6 |
| ID4 | Secondary | I | 2 |

But i was wondering if there is a way to rearrange/alternate the P/I values, something like this:
(alternate between I/P but keep the type primary first, and get the bigger value per P/I)

| ID | Type | I/P | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Primary | I | 8 |
| ID5 | Primary | P | 3 |
| ID6 | Primary | I | 4 |
| ID5 | Primary | P | 3 |
| ID3 | Secondary | P | 6 |
| ID4 | Secondary | I | 2 |

Comment: your starting DF has two 'P' in the DF, the expected output has three 'P'. seems to be  a typo

Comment: It's a typo indeed, i'm sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it

**Note**: your starting DF has two 'P' in the DF, the expected output has three 'P'. seems to be a typo

```
# create a temp seq based on type and i/p
# count for 'I' and 'P' both starts from 0
# sort the result with type and seq


out=df.assign(seq=df.groupby(['Type','I/P']).cumcount()).sort_values(['Type','seq','I/P']).drop(columns='seq')

out
```

```
ID  Type    I/P     Value
0   ID1     Primary     I   8
4   ID5     Primary     P   3
1   ID2     Primary     I   3
5   ID6     Primary     I   4
3   ID4     Secondary   I   2
2   ID3     Secondary   P   6
```

Comment: @Simon, Great! upvote/accept is stackoverflow synonym for Thanks. consider accepting/upvoting if it worked, as you stated.