# Sort values and re order after

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

**Context**

I have a table in this format:

| File | IDR | IDC | Type | I/P | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ID1 | Primary | P | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | ID2 | Secondary | P | 6 |
| 1 | 1 | ID3 | Primary | I | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | ID4 | Primary | I | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | ID5 | Secondary | P | 10 |

Each ['File'] have has its own IDR. Each ['IDR'] has an IDC with a type  (Primary/Secondary) and a value.

**The problem**

I need to sort the ['Values'] descending, but giving priority to Primary and Secondary after.

The 2 most important columns are File and IDR.

First I tried sorting the values:

```py
df3 = df2.groupby(['filename', 'ID_R']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by=['Type', 'Value'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Now I need to mix between P/I. I tried to mix the previous code with:

```py
.assign(seq=df.groupby(['Type', 'I/P']).cumcount()).sort_values(['Type', 'seq', 'I/P']).drop(columns='seq')
```

But this way the first `groupby(['filename', 'ID_R'])` is ignored.

**Desired Output**:

| File | IDR | IDC | Type | I/P | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ID3 | Primary | I | 7 |
| 1 | 1 | ID1 | Primary | P | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | ID2 | Secondary | P | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | ID4 | Primary | I | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | ID5 | Secondary | P | 10 |

Comment: Welcome! (1) could you supply some actual data in your first table instead of `...`? Preferably the same data from your desired output, but pre-sorted; (2) your second code block doesn't execute.

Comment: @IanThompson Hello! I just edited the question! It is important to preserver the file, and IDR , because each file have his own IDR . And de IDC are from the IDR

Comment: What do you mean "mix"?

Comment: intercalate between P and I , even if the "I" value  is lowers than the "P", and the next row put the next bigger value of "P", and the next row the bigger of "I" and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Could you sort all the columns at once?

```py
print(df.sort_values([
    "File",
    "IDR",
    "Type",
    "IDC",
    "Value"
], ascending=[True, True, True, False, True,]))
```

```
   File  IDR  IDC       Type I/P  Value
2     1    1  ID3    Primary   I      7
0     1    1  ID1    Primary   P      5
1     1    1  ID2  Secondary   P      6
3     2    2  ID4    Primary   I      8
4     2    2  ID5  Secondary   P     10
```

Comment: This idea its very close! but this way you'll get  the same as my first code, because it doesnt mix between I/P

Comment: This returns the desired output in the question. Can you provide example data where it doesn't and what that output should look like?

Comment: The "mix" i want it is on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620994/rearrange-mix-column-pandas